# Pandoc: How can I not escape backslashes in YAML metadata?

Tags: yaml, latex, pandoc

Pandoc can use a YAML header in Markdown or a defaults or metadata file for all source types where one can store variables to use in the template. Is it possible to not escape backslashes and LaTeX commands inside these metadata variables?

For example, I'd have this line in my YAML header: `phone: +49\,123\,456789`. When converting, Pandoc escapes the backslashes, so it becomes `+49\textbackslash,123\textbackslash,456789`. This is unwanted, as I want LaTeX to interpret `\,` and turn it into thin spaces.

I also tried wrapping it in `''` or as block with `|`, so YAML itself doesn't escape anything, but this seems to be Pandoc itself doing the conversion, not the YAML interpreter.

#### Minimum reproducible example

src.md:

```
Some text
```

defaults.yaml:

```yaml
template: ./tpl.tex
metadata:
  phone: +49\,123\,456789
```

tpl.tex:

```latex
Phone number: $phone$

Markdown body:
$body$
```

Output with `pandoc --defaults defaults.yaml src.md --to latex`:

```latex
Phone number: +49\textbackslash,123\textbackslash,456789

Markdown body:
Some text
```

Should be:

```latex
Phone number: +49\,123\,456789

Markdown body:
Some text
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: please provide us a  minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sure, my bad, should have done that from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metadata will always be escaped; the easiest way is to do what you want is to define a variable instead of metadata.

```
---
variables:
  phone: +49\,123\,456789
---
```

Contrary to metadata values, variables are inserted verbatim into the template.

Comment: Ah nice, wondered what the difference was when I saw that in the manual, but didn't think of trying it for this. Only downside, there doesn't seem to be a variable-file option like there is metadata-file. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this unicode character: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+202F

Then

```
template: ./tpl.tex
metadata:
  phone: +49 123 456789
```

gets translated via `pandoc --defaults defaults.yaml src.md --to latex -o test.tex` to the following `.tex` file:

```
Phone number: +49\,123\,456789

Markdown body:
Some text
```

Comment: Thank you, this obviously solves this specific case. Not any other case there one would want to include LaTeX commands in yaml metadata though..